# Creating image from html HTML without use of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am looking for a solution to convert html element and it's content into image object which I could send with email attachment. Most of the solutions and JavaScript libraries I've found are based on Canvas element (HTML5), but as IE8 doesn't support it - those solutions can't be used. Does anyone have any solutions which could be supported for all browsers from ie8?

Comment: With IE8 support required, this is simply not doable. IE8 is very much dead and if you cannot support a feature or two for IE8, that should not be an issue - focus on the people you _can_ provide with the feature and tell people on older browsers that their browser does not support it.

Comment: I flagged as too broad: any answer (other than this can't be done in JS) is going to be too long and require server side code. Have you considered exporting as a PDF instead?

Comment: Well i thought of server side handling of this problem and converting to PDF, but for my situation it would have been big workarounds, but I'll guess I'll have to stick with first option, still thanks for replies

Comment: May I recommend to use some [IE8 era technologies](https://www.google.com/search?q=camera+soufflet&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMI7e6W8ZWtyAIVDJOUCh3cWwAX&biw=1216&bih=699#imgrc=eeorvHLFofyAbM%3A) ?

Comment: Thank you, decided to not support IE8 at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must tell you that I have researched a lot on this and I must tell you that **html2canvas** is the best among all to get the images of html content.
So you better change your browser.
I am just saying this so that you wont waste much of your valuable time.

Use Html2Canvas for taking screen shot .Its very easy .. just include the html2canvas js files.. you will get from [Here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases)

and some simple codes . Refer this -> [Click Here](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html)

**NOTE :**  *Please download the latest release of html2canvas ,  now its very much improved in new realease , for eg:
1.supports transform images.
2.By far gives better quality images than before.*

Comment: I guess this _is_ the best answer we can hope for. A link to it would have been a nice addition :)

Comment: @somethinghere added :)